# Automatically Get the Latest Version of a Shapefile From ONS Open Geography Portal

Tags: python, shapefile, geopandas, ons-api

I am trying to automate a data pipeline in Python.

Currently I manually download the latest version of the **Local Authority Districts UK BUC shapefile** from: https://geoportal.statistics.gov.uk/datasets/local-authority-districts-december-2020-uk-buc?geometry=-39.021%2C51.099%2C34.148%2C59.780 and open it with Geopandas.

I am able to get the same shapefile via the API Explorer using the following:

```py
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
import requests
import json

data = requests.get("https://opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/69dc11c7386943b4ad8893c45648b1e1_0.geojson")
lad_gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_features(data.json(),crs=4326)
lad_gdf.head()
```

```py
OUT:

                                            geometry  OBJECTID    LAD20CD               LAD20NM  ...     LONG        LAT   Shape__Area  Shape__Length
0  POLYGON ((-1.24224 54.72297, -1.24194 54.72272...         1  E06000001            Hartlepool  ... -1.27018  54.676140  9.602987e+07   51065.295913
1  POLYGON ((-1.19860 54.58287, -1.16664 54.55423...         2  E06000002         Middlesbrough  ... -1.21099  54.544670  5.523139e+07   35500.386745
2  POLYGON ((-0.79189 54.55824, -0.80042 54.55101...         3  E06000003  Redcar and Cleveland  ... -1.00608  54.567520  2.483428e+08   78449.389240
3  POLYGON ((-1.19319 54.62905, -1.20018 54.62350...         4  E06000004      Stockton-on-Tees  ... -1.30664  54.556911  2.052314e+08   87566.566061
4  POLYGON ((-1.43836 54.59508, -1.42333 54.60313...         5  E06000005            Darlington  ... -1.56835  54.535339  1.988128e+08   91926.839545

[5 rows x 11 columns]
```

I can't find a version of the above api that will always download the latest version of the shapefile as opposed to the December 2020 version.

Is there a way to ensure that I always download the newest release?

Thanks